# DataFrames for Apache Spark MLLib online real-time single-item prediction, seriously?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-dataset

Having trained the mllib model, do I have to convert every incoming item in an online system to a DataFrame to call a predict/transform-like method on it?
Looks like an overkill with a high risk of time/memory-related issues.

Can I build/transform/predict just one Row somehow, or something like that?
(Solution in Scala is preferable)

*I've found a text where authors say they've implemented something of their own for this: https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/training-and-serving-nlp-models-using-spark-mllib*

Comment: I've written my own wrapper over XxxModels, but I feel uncool now.